# Как изменить подзаголовок слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

нашёл слайдер на просторах интернета https://codepen.io/bryan-erwin/pen/dJEYVr , пытаюсь настроить под себя. Как 
установить подзаголовок(caption-subhead) для каждого слайда?

`<div class="caption-subhead"><span>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </span></div>`

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в коде Js для каждого слайда свои заголовки и описание.

Меняйте на то, что Вам необходимо:

```js
let slide_data = [
    {
     'src':'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506765336936-bb05e7e06295?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=d40582dbbbb66c7e0812854374194c2e&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80',
     'title':'Slide 1',
     'copy':'DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT.'
    },
    ...
```